# Hibernate criteria and/or with many-to-many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria

This is the query i'm running:

```
    List<Coupon> coupons = getDb().createCriteria(Coupon.class)
    .add(Restrictions.le("validFrom", startTime.getTime()))
    .add(Restrictions.ge("validUntil", startTime.getTime()))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("user", user))
    .createAlias("spots", "spotsAlias")
    .add(Restrictions.or(
            Restrictions.eq("isGlobal", true),
            Restrictions.eq("spotsAlias.id", spot.getId())
            ))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("isRedeemed", false))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("isDeleted", false))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("isActive", true))
    .addOrder(Order.asc("isGlobal"))
    .addOrder(Order.desc("validFrom"))
    .list();
```

it's supposed to get all coupons that are:

- valid at startTime
- related to user
- global or related to a specific spot
- not redeemed
- not deleted
- activated

the coupons are in many-to-many relationship with spots. the relationship works - this query does return coupons that are specifically related to the queried spot. Unfortunately, it never returns global coupons, even when there are no "local" coupons in the database at all.

Any suggestions? help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: try using disjunction()?

Answer (score 0):

Try using disjunction and see:

```
 .add( Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.eq("global", Boolean.TRUE))
                              .add(Restrictions.eq("spotsAlias.id", spot.getId())))
```

Also if global is a property in your Entity, then you need to use :

```
Restrictions.eq("global", Boolean.TRUE)
```

Also if you refer to [Restrictions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html) class, it has only

```
eq(String propertyName, Object value)
```

method which takes object as second parameter and not a primitive type.

Comment: no. still the same result. doesn't return coupons with isGlobal=true.

Comment: is global a property in your entity?

Comment: "could not resolve property: global of: com.pinkpark.model.Coupon"

Comment: yes please use (propertyName, object) in all your restrictions and your Order.asc(propertyName) / Order.desc(propertyName)

Comment: do you have Boolean.TRUE in place of true?, rightnow you are passing in primitive types to a method that accepts objects as second parameter.